# Apply conditional formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, gs-conditional-formatting

I have checked multiple threads for the result I am looking for and have not had any luck.

What I am trying to accomplish is change a cells font color and size based on a specific value. (if col B1:B equals "Changes:", change font to red and bold)

I was able to get the following to work:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    if (e) { 
        var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
        var r = e.source.getActiveRange();  

        // If you want to be specific
        // do not work in first row
        // do not work in other sheets except "Sheet3"
        if (r.getRow() != 1 && ss.getName() == "Sheet3") {

            // E.g. status column is 2nd (B)
            status = ss.getRange(r.getRow(), 2).getValue();

            // Specify the range with which You want to highlight
            // with some reading of API you can easily modify the range     selection properties
            // (e.g. to automatically select all columns)
            rowRange = ss.getRange(r.getRow(),1,1,19);

            // This changes font color
          if (status == 'CHANGES:') {
                rowRange.setFontColor("#FF0000");
                rowRange.setFontWeight("bold");
          } else if (status == 'DELETIONS:') {
                rowRange.setFontColor("##FF0000");
                rowRange.setFontWeight("bold");
            // DEFAULT
            } else if (status == '') { 
                rowRange.setFontColor("#000000");
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with my script is I want it to run on a trigger ("on Open" or "on Change"), not "on Edit". I use a script to copy data from Sheet1 and paste it to Sheet3. After the copy/paste script runs, I want the formatting script to run on Sheet3 and edit the cells per the above.